# Why is $H_n(K,A) \simeq H_n(K^{(n+1)})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $K$ be a CW-complex and $A$ a subcomplex. Define by $K^{(n)}$ the union of the $n$-th skeleton of $K$ with $A$. Bredon states without explaining that 
$$H_n(K,A) \simeq H_n(K^{(n+1)})$$
in order to derive the isomorphism between cellular homology and singular homology (the above are all singular homology). However, I think that there is something that I am missing, since constructing the circle as a CW-complex with two $0$-cells and two $1$-cells in the standard way and letting $A$ be the two $0$-cells would yield a contradiction with $n=1$.

What does Bredon mean by the equality?

---

To be quite explicit, this is what happens in Bredon:

[image]

He then proceeds to define the *relative cellular homology* based on the complex $C_{\bullet}=H_{\bullet}(K^{(\bullet)},K^{(\bullet-1)})$ with the boundary given by $\beta_{\bullet}=j_{\bullet} \circ \partial_{\bullet}$, where $j$ and $\partial$ come from the obvious long exact sequences.

Then, after defining the objects I said above and computing things, he arrives at

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is correct, and this statement certainly isn't true as stated.  It appears that the intended statement is $$H_n(K,A) \simeq H_n(K^{(n+1)},A),$$ and that in fact everywhere Bredon wrote homology of $K^{(i)}$ for some $i$ he actually meant homology of the pair $(K^{(i)},A)$.  Instead of using exact sequences of the pairs $(K^{(i)},K^{(i-1)})$, you then instead use exact sequences of the triples $(K^{(i)},K^{(i-1)},A)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've put context on the question, please elaborate on it if possible.

Comment: I've updated the answer--it appears my original guess was correct.

Comment: Great! This indeed makes a lot of sense. However, two things bother me: the first is that he does not make that notation explicit, which is quite annoying (but this is personal, just letting it out), and the second is that there is a moment where he refers to the reduced homology $\widetilde{H}_{n-1}(K^{(n-1)})$, which is a bit weird in this new outlook. Any reason why he would do that?
In any case, I will check if everything checks out under this new POV. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hmm, I think it can be just to include the possibility that $A= \emptyset$ all along and make things unified, right?

Comment: Yeah, taking reduced homology may be necessary in the case that $A=\emptyset$.  Frankly, I would guess that this is not a case of inexplicit notation, but rather an accidental error.  It may have arisen if he originally wrote up the material for non-relative homology, and then later realized he needed it for relative homology and just modified what he had written but missed some parts that needed modification.